# Open webpage in fullscreen in Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

There is a fullscreen mode in Safari on iOS. Is it possible to activate this through javascript or similar?

Thanks

Comment: It happens when your page has the "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" meta tag, and it's launched from an icon on the device "desktop".

Comment: Downvoter please explain

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, there is no way to toggle the fullscreen mode in Safari on iOS using javascript.

In order for a web page to run in fullscreen mode, you need to add the following meta tag, and the page needs to be started from a bookmark on the home screen:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

However, you *can* detect if the page is running in fullscreen mode or not with javascript using the read only property:

```
window.navigator.standalone
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: In my test window.navigator.standalone always console false in fullscreen mode and non-fullscreen mode.

Its non-working answer.

Comment: Going through the bookmark route did not work for me, but clicking the share button, then "Add to Home Screen" did. Once I open from my 'desktop' then it goes into fullscreen.

Comment: looks like once you are in full screen mode there is no way of getting out of it?

Answer (score 1):

Aftier iOS >= 12, There is only way to toggle to fullscreen through native API in Safari.

```js
    if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    } else {
      const el = document.documentElement;
      el.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
```

Comment: The document has no fullscreen functions on my iPhone. In a debug console:

```javascript
(() => { var keyz = []; for(var k in document) keyz.push(k); return keyz })().filter(k => /fullscreen/i.test(k))
```

returns `[]`

Comment: I'm afraid on iOS 14.3 I don't see it either.

Comment: I believe this only works on iPad, not iPhone. See the notes for iOS Safari here: https://caniuse.com/?search=fullscreen

Comment: doesn't seem to work  on iPad iOs 14.4.2

Comment: Only works on iPad AND only on `<video>` elements.