# IOS10 fullscreen safari Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, safari

I'm trying to make a div go fullscreen, when a user clicks a button on a website.

Only thing is, every browser seems to want to work except for Safari on IOS.

What will I need to do to be able to make it fullscreen? I've tried researching, but unable to find anything.

Heres my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goFullscreen(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id); 

    var isInFullScreen = (document.fullscreenElement && document.fullscreenElement !== null) ||
        (document.webkitFullscreenElement && document.webkitFullscreenElement !== null) ||
        (document.mozFullScreenElement && document.mozFullScreenElement !== null) ||
        (document.msFullscreenElement && document.msFullscreenElement !== null);

    var docElm = document.documentElement;
    if (!isInFullScreen) {
        if (element.requestFullscreen) {
            element.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
           element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
            element.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46544156/5913564 anwser work for you ?

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned on many posts, there is no way to switch to fullscreen on IOS >=10 in Safari and Chrome. It is because the Fullscreen API is not supported:

- [Can I Use Full Screen API](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen)
- [open webpage in fullscreen in Safari on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485919/open-webpage-in-fullscreen-in-safari-on-ios#)
- [Full screen api HTML5 and Safari (iOS 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822739/full-screen-api-html5-and-safari-ios-6)

You have two possible tricks:

- **Inform the user to switch to landscape mode**. Indeed, you can't hardcode this and iOS Chrome can't do this too ([Prevent orientation change in iOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298467/prevent-orientation-change-in-ios-safari)).
- if your webpage is **exported in a web app** and you configure the meta balizes correctly ([Optimizing Full Screen Mobile Web App for iOS](http://www.onlywebpro.com/2015/07/19/optimizing-full-screen-mobile-web-app-for-ios/)).

Comment: i do not understand the first trick. do I open in full screen a page if I'm in landscape mode? how? thank you

Comment: You can just inform the user to rotate its phone if he is in portrait mode.

Comment: @JérémieBoulay I don't see anything about going to landscape mode in the question... but still useful information

Comment: @DavidCallanan Going to landscape is a trick to have your web view in full screen.

Comment: @JérémieBoulay Oh I see that makes sense!

Comment: Are you sure landscape is a trick to show fullscreen? On my iPhone Safari I still see the browser toolbar when I rotate to landscape. If I scroll the page down then the toolbar slides offscreen, but it reappears when I start scrolling back up.